# WSO2: Passing NameValueCCSID and NameValueData to IBM MQ using MQRFH2 header

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to send XML messages to IBM MQ over JMS transport, using a WSO2 proxy service.
I have already configured the JMS transport on server level and successfully published some messages to the queue. I can see the published messages using MQ console.

Now, I have requirement to send additional meta-data using MQRFH2 header.

I should populate the NameValueCCSID field with value 1208 and NameValueData field with an XML document in format

```
<COMSMS>
  <FIN_Input>
  ...
```

The RFH2 header should have only one NameValue COMSMS.

I already searched through IBM and WSO2 documentation but was not able to figure out how to pass data for this custom NameValue (neither NameValueCCSID nor NameValueData). The WSO2 documentation only provides examples for predefined properties which have a JMS-MQ mapping.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard JMS properties, they will be stored in the `usr` folder of [RHF2 header](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messages-mqrfh2-header-jms):

```
myMessage.setStringProperty("MyPropertyName", "MyPropertyValue");
```

You can use any arbitrary String as the value, so it could also be an XML alike value - this is a matter of application design. A more fine-grained setting of separate message properties will make it easier for the receiving application to specify message selectors.

There are also methods for properties of other data types then String available.

Comment: Do you have any idea if is it possible to store those properties in own folders, outside the `usr` folder? I have requirement (which I was not aware of) that those properties should not be sent inside usr folder and now I'm trying to find a solution. Custom folder seems to me as option, but I have no idea how to force JMS to create them. I already tried to use syntax `COMSMS.FIN_Input` as property name, but it didn't work. I got error `Cannot invoke "org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.SessionWrapper.getSession()" because "invalid" is null` in WSO" error log.

Comment: I assume the receiving application is not doing JMS and it is expecting some other folders. When using JMS for the message producing application you are restricted what is documented here (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messages-mqrfh2-header-jms). That is, some standard JMS properties go to specific folders, all other user defined properties go to the usr folder. If you want to create any arbitrary folder, you would need to use the MQ Java API instead of JMS.  The MQ Java API knows a MQRFH2 class which allows you to set fields to folders other than usr.